# Add a minlength condition for combined field values

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a first name and last name field in my form, and I need to enforce a rule that the combined length of the first and last names should be at least 4 characters. Is this possible in JSON schema v4 validator? My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "first_name" : "Fo",
    "last_name"  : "L",
    .....
}
```

I cannot keep a full_name field in my form - it needs to be two separate fields first_name and last_name. I know that one way is to concatenate the first and last names in the backend and then have a validator like so:

```
$full_name = $first_name + $last_name;
--------------------------------------
"full_name": {
        "type": "string",
        "error_code": "incorrect_length",
        "anyOf": [
            { "minLength": 4 },
            { "maxLength": 0 }
        ]
    },
```

However, I am looking at a method in which I don't have to create a dummy full_name field. Is it possible to validate with the first_name and last_name fields only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with JSON Schema, although not in a very nice way, and doing it on the back end is preferable. There's no key word to achive this, so you would have to use `oneOf` and cover the valid cases like so:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "minLength": 1
        },
        "last_name": {
          "minLength": 3
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "minLength": 2
        },
        "last_name": {
          "minLength": 2
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "minLength": 3
        },
        "last_name": {
          "minLength": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```